# How to design entity to deserialise JSON string to C# Entity

Tags: c#, json

I would like to have some of your suggestions on how we can design this complex entity so that it can be easily be deserialized using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

JSON string would look like:

```
{       
    "name": "ABC MANAGEMENT"        
    "statusId": {       
      "mnemo": "110"        
      "label": "Validated"      
    }       
    "tdMnemo": "TD177"      
    "productsTradedOnDesks": [      
      {     
        "secptdAssetClassId": 374       
        "secptdAssetClassName": "ABCD"      
        "secptdInstrumentId": 499       
        "secptdInstrumentName": "Lending and Borrowing"     
        "sectptdVlkMap": [      
          {     
            "secpVlkmVlkId": 25     
            "secpVlkmVlkLabel": "Lend and Borrow"       
          }     
        ]       
      }     
      {     
        "secptdAssetClassId": 383       
        "secptdAssetClassName": "FXH"       
        "secptdInstrumentId": 453       
        "secptdInstrumentName": "FWD and SWP"       
        "sectptdVlkMap": [      
          {     
            "secpVlkmVlkId": 33     
            "secpVlkmVlkLabel": "Risk"      
          }     
        ]       
      }     
      {     
        "secptdAssetClassId": 383       
        "secptdAssetClassName": "FXG"       
        "secptdInstrumentId": 407       
        "secptdInstrumentName": "NDF"       
        "sectptdVlkMap": [      
          {     
            "secpVlkmVlkId": 33     
            "secpVlkmVlkLabel": "Hedging"       
          }     
        ]       
      }     
      {     
        "secptdAssetClassId": 383       
        "secptdAssetClassName": "FXJ"       
        "secptdInstrumentId": 414       
        "secptdInstrumentName": "SPT"       
        "sectptdVlkMap": []     
      }      
    ]       
  }
```

Comment: Not sure what is it that you are having trouble with? Seems pretty straight forward. You would have something like `public class Company` and a `Company` has a `Status` object and a collection of `ProductTrade` object, etc...

Comment: You can go to the website [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) which was developed for this reason (and is using Json.NET behind). By the way ... the properties in your json data should be terminated with an **,**.

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio, if your JSON format is correct, you can copy JSON in memory, click on empty cs file, click **Edit -> Paste JSON as classes**, and you get your classes directly.

This should work for you.

```
Data here is starting class 
  - Holds a reference to StatusId class
  - Holds a reference to ProductTraded array

Every ProductTraded object 
  - Holds a reference to ProductMapDetail array
```

You can create objects and assign values. Then, serialize with JSON.net to check the output. If output matches, it will get deserialized to Data class.

```
public class Data
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public StatusId statusId { get; set; }
    public string tdMnemo { get; set; }
    public ProductTraded[] productsTradedOnDesks { get; set; }
}

public class StatusId
{
    public string mnemo { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class ProductTraded
{
    public int secptdAssetClassId { get; set; }
    public string secptdAssetClassName { get; set; }
    public int secptdInstrumentId { get; set; }
    public string secptdInstrumentName { get; set; }
    public ProductMapDetail[] sectptdVlkMap { get; set; }
}

public class ProductMapDetail
{
    public int secpVlkmVlkId { get; set; }
    public string secpVlkmVlkLabel { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I approach making c# models to deserialize JSON to

- A member that is contained like `{...}` should be represented with a class
- A member that is contained like `[ ... ]` should be represented with a `List<T>`, or other `IEnumerable`
- A member that is contained like `"..."`, should be a primitive value, such as a `string` or `int`.
- Your Json should only have one root member.  It can be a list or an object.